# Horizon of short vs. long term forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, terminology

I have frequently read about long term and short term forecasting in time series analysis, but I didn't get how this is determined. Is this empirical values and why? How can I determine the horizon in different term forecasting (like based on percentage of input data)? I would appreciate references.

Comment: Can you explain this in even more detail? I am having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: sorry for my poor language. i am asking what is the horizon (i.e. steps ahead) in time series forecasting when saying long or short term. one steps ahead we can sure it's short term, but how much steps ahead would it be long term? and how it is dertermined that way? would it this dependent on the percentage such as 1% is short term and 10% is long term?

Comment: Percentage of what? Like if the sample covers 10 years and we are forecasting 1 year ahead, we have 10%?

Comment: yes, i am wondering whether the horizon of so called long or short term forecating is dependent on the percentage of input data.